# Chaining virtual file system drivers in rasterio

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio

In plain `gdal` it's quite straightforward to chain multiple `vsi` drivers to e.g. directly access a `.tif.gz` file:

```
import gdal
import rasterio as rio

## just an example, no real URL

# will work
ds = gdal.Open('/vsigzip//vsicurl/https://testdata.com/testimage.tif.gz')

# won't work
ds = rio.open('/vsigzip/https://testdata.com/testimage.tif.gz')
```

Is it an issue with chaining or can `rasterio` just not handle `.gz` files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran through this and gzip support within RasterIO (v1.0.21) checks out ok. Seems you've just missed the `//vsicurl`.

```
import rasterio as rio

ds = rio.open('/vsigzip//vsicurl/http://localhost:8000/example.tif.gz')
```

The http server needs to support range requests, but if it doesn't RasterIO will produce a specific error message.

Interestingly the [Apache Commons VFS scheme](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/datasets.html) doesn't seem to work here;

```
ds = rio.open('gzip+http://localhost:8000/example.tif.gz')
```

Produces the following. Note missing `/` before `vsicurl`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/rasterio-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rasterio/env.py", line 423, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/rasterio-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rasterio/__init__.py", line 216, in open
    s = DatasetReader(path, driver=driver, **kwargs)
  File "rasterio/_base.pyx", line 215, in rasterio._base.DatasetBase.__init__
rasterio.errors.RasterioIOError: '/vsizip/vsicurl/http://localhost:8000/example.tif.gz' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
```